# How to use service layer in an idiomatic way

Tags: rust

Coming from .NET/Java background, I am trying to build a largish monitoring app which can mainly be considered as crud app. I am using `axum` for rest api. I am having trouble choosing between different structural approaches after inspecting many examples. Let's say that I have user service:

1. I can directly use the database connection inside the handler to execute a query

```rust
pub async fn get_user(State(state): State<ServerState>) -> Result<(), Error> {
      user_account::Entity::find()
            .filter(user_account::Column::Username.eq("some username"))
            .one(&state.db.conn)
            .await
}
```

2. I can call the function directly inside the handler

```rust
// state holds a reference to db which could also be an extension.

pub async fn get_user(State(state): State<ServerState>) -> Result<(), Error> {
      service::user::get_by_login(&state.db.conn, "some username").await
}
```

3. I can wrap the service into a struct, put that in `State` or an `Extension` and use that inside the handler:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Service {
    db: db::Service,
}

let user_service = service::user::Service::new(db.clone());

// use .with_state(...) to register the service


pub async fn get_user(State(state): State<ServerState>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    state.user_service.get_by_login("some username").await?;
}
```

I like the 3rd approach since I feel like it provides better separation of concerns (and testability?) but I am not sure if it is too much abstraction and boilerplate for just some simple crud operations. Is it considered a good practice to call functions directly like in 2nd example?

Any suggestions, ideas, experiences to share?

Comment: First strategy is, do the simplest thing that works (but don't get too sloppy), and refactor it later if you need. Opposite is isolate all implementation details (but don't get too abstract). I think the second is a better goal, but a lot depends on your circumstances. If implementation details never change, you've completely wasted time isolating them. If you aren't going to have time to refactor later, the over-simple implementation will be technical debt that wastes time later. The best way to decide is to see the future. Barring that, look at how much code churns in your environment.

Comment: What we do is have a global `State` struct, and implement a trait on it for each capability, such as "database connection factory" or "LDAP authentication provider" and then each route is generic, bounding the state on only the capability traits it needs. This may fall into the category of "too abstract" but we find it helps us effectively inventory what capabilities each route needs, and define a clear-cut API for using those capabilities independently from all of the others.

Comment: @cdhowie is there any example repository demonstrating this approach? Do you directly use the db connection factory inside the handler?

Comment: @CemreMengü It's a proprietary application so we don't have any published code showing the technique, unfortunately. The "connection factory" is simply a trait that is implemented on the state type, and then yes, the handler can use methods from this trait on the state (which must be bounded on the trait).